# A dataframe contain '\t' how to avoid '\t' from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i convert a dataset to dataframe the datas contain \t with the numbers.
my original data is 0 50 234567 like this
but 
create thedataframe,
the datas will be
0\t50\t234567

How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: What format is the "dataset"? A text file? It may be a tab separated file - much like a comma separated file but with tabs. In that case `read_csv` can be used - just define a different separator.

Comment: Please post your code, how you read your csv, and what the csv looks like.

Comment: Try using the `str.replace` function in pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html